# What's the grammatical or syntactical term for the way these sentences are structured?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

> As a mother, Linda enjoys spending time with her children.
>
> Despising commoners, Bartholomew shuns the beggars.
>
> Once a master of the blade, Shigeru gazes longingly at the weapon before him.

I can't figure out how to describe the format of these sentences, where the subject is preceded by a description. Is there a term for this or a formal way of describing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As a mother** (prepositional phrase) and **Despising commoners** (participle phrase) are both fronting free modifiers: they modify the whole of their respective main clauses.

**Once a master of the blade** is a fronting bound modifier adjectivally modifying Shigeru - it is the equivalent of a relative clause (Shingeru, who was once a master of the blade, ...)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!